# Why data added to arraylist is not saved

Tags: java

I'm looping through two list of objects. I'm pushing data from list#2 into a hashmap and adding this to a new array list. But the data in the hashmap doesn't seems to be persisted.

List1 is a unique set of objects
List2 is list of objects which has redundant data which needs to be collected together into the unique list1

```
for (POJOClass1 uniqitm : uniqitms)  //list1
{   
    aggrdata.clear();

    for (POJOClass1 redundantitm : redundantitms) //list2               
    {
        if (redundantitm.getResource().equals(uniqitm.getResource()))   //For all objects matching uniq itm, i push below 2 attributes into a hashmap
        {
            aggrdata.put(redundantitm.getMan(), redundantitm.getData_map());
        }
    }

    uniqitm.setMap2(aggrdata); //aggregated data is pushed into the uniq itm object
    uniqitm.setMap(null);
    uniqitm.setMan(null);
    final.add(uniqitm);         //uniq itm object is added to a new array list to be used outside
}
final.stream().forEach(s-> System.out.println(s.getResource()+" : "+s.getMap2()));  //The aggregated data doesnt seem to persist correctly
```

I expect the output to contain the aggregated data from all the objects from list2.

Comment: Where is your `list2` and other stuff ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the hashmap needed to be declared within the forloop for it to work right.
aggrdata.clear() was not sufficient.

```
for (POJOClass1 uniqitm : uniqitms)  //list1
{   
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> aggrdata= new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();

    for (POJOClass1 redundantitm : redundantitms) //list2               
    {
        if (redundantitm.getResource().equals(uniqitm.getResource()))   //For all objects matching uniq itm, i push below 2 attributes into a hashmap
        {
            aggrdata.put(redundantitm.getMan(), redundantitm.getData_map());
        }
    }

    uniqitm.setMap2(aggrdata); //aggregated data is pushed into the uniq itm object
    uniqitm.setMap(null);
    uniqitm.setMan(null);
    final.add(uniqitm);         //uniq itm object is added to a new array list to be used outside
}
```